# How to boot from USB

Tags: dual-boot

I have downloaded ubuntu-14.04.2 desktop-amd64.iso.

Is it possible that we copy the iso file into our pendrive and then boot it from Pendrive after restarting?

If yes, could you please provide me with the steps for that.

To be frank, I am not good with the computers

My laptop is Lenevo G580

Comment: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/FromUSBStick

Comment: Are you planning on installing off this drive? Also, is the computer EFI (WIndows 8 from the factory) or regular BIOS?

Comment: @Githlar :mine is windows 7 and i am using regular BIOS

Answer (score 1):

Your best bet is [YUMI](http://www.pendrivelinux.com/yumi-multiboot-usb-creator/) if you're currently running Windows. The process after downloading is very simple; you select the Linux distro you would like to use, and point it to your iso, and begin the process. It also allows for multiple OS to be set up on your USB.

Answer (score 0):

(Sorry for the delay in getting this answer to you, while I do have experience with creating BootUSBs, they're made from Ubuntu and I had to be sure my Windows methods still worked =)

Ellie Zffie's answer is technically correct, but the YUMI site even states that the goal of the project is to make the OS bootable but not necessarily installable. That said, it's worth a shot to try it. However, if it doesn't work there is another, more correct (but less user-friendly) solution.

The Ubuntu ISO is what's known as a "hybrid" ISO. That is, it's an ISO with a partition table just like a hard disk. Recent versions of Ubuntu even have an EFI partition to make it bootable via both EFI and USB. This means that the ISO can be copied directly to a USB drive. This, however, has a couple of drawbacks:

- It will erase all data on the drive
- The USB drive that is the result of the process will have two read-only partitions. It's possible to add additional partitions, but Windows has a tendency to ignore additional partitions on flash media.
- Using [dd for Windows](http://www.chrysocome.net/dd) is not for the feint of heart and could result in major data loss if done improperly.

So, I don't even recommend that. Luckily, I have experience with building customized Ubuntu BootUSBs. The process to make an Ubuntu USB BootUSB  manually is actually fairly trivial and consists of 3 steps:

1. Extract the contents of the ISO to the USB drive
2. Run the Syslinux installer
3. Rename a file

That's the short version anyway. Here are the exact steps to get a working, guaranteed installable Ubuntu LiveUSB without a read-only filesystem:

#### Download Prerequisites

1. Download the Ubuntu ISO.
2. Download [syslinux](http://www.syslinux.org). If you're planning on installing 14.04 LTS (Trusty), get [syslinux-4.05.zip](https://www.kernel.org/pub/linux/utils/boot/syslinux/syslinux-4.05.zip). For 14.10 (Utopic), or 15.04 (Vivid) get [syslinux-6.03.zip](https://www.kernel.org/pub/linux/utils/boot/syslinux/syslinux/6.03.zip).
3. Get a copy of an archive extraction tool such a 7-zip for extracting the ISO (I believe that WinRAR and/or WinZip also work for this purpose) and install it.

#### Extract the files

1. Extract syslinux-4.05.zip or syslinux-6.03.zip to your Desktop.
2. Extract the ISO contents to your USB drive using 7-zip/WinZip/WinRAR. If you use 7-zip it will create an extra folder called "[BOOT]". This isn't necessary to keep.

#### Install Syslinux

1. Open an administrator command prompt.
2. `cd C:\Users\[Username]\Desktop\syslinux-4.05` (or syslinux-6.03 depending on the version you downloaded)
3. `cd win32` or `cd win64` depending on your version of Windows. (Hint: check Computer->Properties)
4. `syslinux --active --install X:` (replace X: with the drive letter of your USB drive)

#### Rename the configuration file

1. On your USB drive, locate the "isolinux" folder
2. Inside this folder, rename isolinux.cfg to syslinux.cfg

Reboot to boot into your new Ubuntu LiveUSB!

Answer (score 0):

I downloaded this and now and creater a ubuntu bootable disc

ow to create a bootable USB stick on Windows
To run Ubuntu from a USB stick, the first thing you need to do is insert a USB stick with at least 2GB of free space into your PC.

The easiest way to put Ubuntu onto your stick is to use the USB installer provided at pendrivelinux.com. You’ll need to download and install and follow the instructions.

Download Pen Drive Linux's USB Installer ›

Now m struck. I am unable to upload the photo as i am new.

I do not know how to part disk